# Show/hide dynamic IDs for Touch devices

Tags: jquery

Need jquery solution for touch devices component. when  touched, "-short" have to hide and "-over" have to show.

id names are created dynamically like "coverage_icons-item_1-short", "coverage_icons-item_2-short", "coverage_icons-item_1-over", "coverage_icons-item_2-over"

How can we control this dynamic created IDs using jquery?

Thanks

```
<li style="width: 31.3333%;">
<img id="coverage_icons-item_1" class="icon ng-scope" data-swap-image="/images/icons-hd/ticked-small.png" data-ng-mouseleave="swapImageSrc()" data-ng-mouseenter="swapImageSrc()" alt="" src="/images/icons-hd/tick.png">
<span id="coverage_icons-item_1-short" style="display: block;">Match interest</span>
<span id="coverage_icons-item_1-over" style="display: none;">Policy Terms of 10-30 years</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Why don't you create the separate class for the touch and touch items and then use the class property to hind and display ?

Comment: Hi Devesh.. Sorry for late reply.. Now we cant add new class name.. Because this project already went to production and HTML code update is freezed. we have access to update only JS files.